# how do i get username from servlet to jsp page to insert it into database i tried using session.getAttribute it didn't work here's my code

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

Login Servlet- Login.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse                            response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if(Validate.checkUser(username, pass))
    {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rs.forward(request, response);

        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/login2/dietsection.html");
    }
```

JSP Page-dietjsp.jsp

```
 <%  
 String username=request.getParameter("username"); 
 session.getAttribute(username);


 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
 java.sql.Connection con =                            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindb",
"root",""); 
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
              ("insert into diet values(?)");
    ps.setString(1, username);

    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

   %>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?. Is the page not displayed.Or are you not getting the value of user name ?

Comment: It does not get the value of username from session.Works fine with html parameters.

Comment: Let go this way.Check this code     if(Validate.checkUser(username, pass))
    {
 session.setAttribute("username", username);
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rs.forward(request, response);
         } . Also remove this line from the if  response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/login2/dietsection.html"); and in the jsp instead of this line String username=request.getParameter("username"); 
 session.getAttribute(username); do this String username= (String)session.getAttribute(username); Check whether it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSP Page-dietjsp.jsp use quotes

```
session.getAttribute("username");
```

Comment: session.getAttribute("username"); returns Object, it should be type casted to String as follows  String username= (String)session.getAttribute(username);